# Java Socket/Server Programming: Socket is not connected

Tags: java, sockets, server

I have been having a go at attempting to do Server Programming in Java recently, and I wanted to create a simple console server interaction.

The problem I have, is whenever the server runs, it always crashes with the main error being a socket exception.

Here is the code:

SOK_CLIENT Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SOK_CLIENT
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
SOK_SERVER SERVER = new SOK_SERVER();
SOK_CLIENT CLIENT = new SOK_CLIENT();
CLIENT.run();
}
public void run() throws Exception
{
Socket SOCK = new Socket("localhost", 1025);
PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(SOCK.getOutputStream());
PS.println("Hello to Server From Client");

InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream());
BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);

String MESSAGE = BR.readLine();
System.out.println(MESSAGE);
}
}
```

Here is the SOK_SERVER Class: (Where the Error is Located)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SOK_SERVER
{
  public SOK_SERVER()
{
try 
{
  run();
}
catch(Exception e) 
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public void run() throws Exception 
{
int PORT = 1025;
ServerSocket SRVSOCKET = new ServerSocket(PORT);
Socket SOCK = new Socket();
System.out.println("Server Starting at Port: " + PORT);
InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream());
BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);
String MESSAGE = BR.readLine();
System.out.println(MESSAGE);
if(MESSAGE != null)
{
PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(SOCK.getOutputStream());
PS.println("Message Recieved");
}
}
}
```

Exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected
at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:796)
at SOK_SERVER.run(SOK_SERVER.java:31)
at SOK_SERVER.<init>(SOK_SERVER.java:16)
at SOK_CLIENT.main(SOK_CLIENT.java:8)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.symbol.JavaClass$JavaMethod.evaluate(JavaClass.java:362)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.handleMethodCall(ExpressionEvaluator.java:92)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.visit(ExpressionEvaluator.java:84)
at koala.dynamicjava.tree.StaticMethodCall.acceptVisitor(StaticMethodCall.java:121)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:38)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:37)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:106)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:29)
at koala.dynamicjava.tree.ExpressionStatement.acceptVisitor(ExpressionStatement.java:101)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.evaluateSequence(StatementEvaluator.java:66)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.java:77)
at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:47)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:246)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:220)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695
```

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you, so please use the *preview* functionality and make sure **all** of your code is properly formatted/indented. And please read about java coding style guidelines. The names you use for your classes and variables makes my brain hurt. Seriously: just the way you write your code makes it 10 times harder to read than it ought to be. Meaning: it takes us 10 times the energy to help you.

Comment: Sorry! This was really my first try at doing the whole bracket on single line thing! Ill try and fix it in the future

Comment: Glad to hear that; but just for the record: naming is as important for readability as formatting is. It is actually even more important, because bad formatting can be fixed mechanically by tools. Bad names ... well, that will always require **manual** work.

Comment: And another hint: as you got a line number ... highlight the corresponding line within your source code. Dont expect us to count those lines manually!

Comment: This is not 'loads of errors'. It is one stack trace for one exception.

Answer (score 2):

You should change `Socket SOCK = new Socket();` in your server code to `Socket SOCK = SRVSOCKET.accept();`

Comment: The thing with that is whenever I run it, the code just does not work! Like it does not even start the server

Comment: @BWhitehead What is the error you are getting after above modification?

Comment: What happens is nothing really happens. It may seem odd but there are no errors, all it says is run SOK_CLIENT. could it be the IDE im using?

Comment: @BWhitehead The problem is you are running client and server together. Try running them separately.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
Socket SOCKET = new Socket();

SOCKET = SRVSOCKET.accept();
```

Implements both classes Runnable and instantiate as a Thread

and call start() method.. not run()

```
SOCK_CLIENT implements Runnable
SOCK_SERVER implements Runnable
```

under your main method

```
SOK_SERVER SERVER = new SOK_SERVER();
SOK_CLIENT CLIENT = new SOK_CLIENT();
Thread t1 = new Thread(SERVER);
Thread t2 = new Thread(CLIENT);

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

And remove `run();` from SOCK_SERVER constructor

Comment: When you try to get some reputation just by copying what another person already wrote; at least try to get the formatting right. And maybe add some explanation using your own words.

Comment: The intialization to `new Socket()` is both pointless and wasteful, as it creates a resource leak.